# Pass Non-Parameters as Parameters to a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
class Food
{
    int Kg, Quality;
public:
    Food(int kg, int quality)
    {
        Kg = kg;
        Quality = quality;
    }
    ~Food(void) {}
};

class Pizza : public Food
{
public:
    int Flavor;

    // Use of undeclared identifiers 'tempKg' 'tempQuality' [Error]
    Pizza(int flavor) : Food(tempKg, tempQuality)
    {
        // I would like to know if i can use these variables as Food arguments
        int tempKg=0, tempQuality=0;
        int Flavor = flavor;
    }

    // This works as it should
    /* Pizza(int flavor, int kg, int quality) : Food(kg, quality)
    {
        int Flavor = flavor;
    } */
};
```

My question is if the parameters that I'm allowed to pass to Food's constructor can only be the parameters declared inside Pizza's constructor?

If they don't necessary need to be, how can I pass parameters into Food that aren't Pizza parameters?

Comment: Have you tried the simple `Pizza(int flavor, int tempKg=0, tempQuality=0) : Food(tempKg, tempQuality)`?

Comment: _This works as it should_ That's because it's the way you're supposed to do it.

Comment: You can't (except for what Sam said). You have to do `Food(0, 0)` directly. If you need some complex calculation to get `tempKg` from `flavor`, put that in an auxiliary function `getKg(flavor)` and use `Food(getKg(flavor),...)` instead.

Comment: You don't need `;` after `}` in function definitions.

Comment: `~Food(void) {}` -- The destructor should be `virtual`.

Comment: If food has meaningful mg and quality, and pizza is food, then pizza must have meaningful mg and quality too. Setting them to zero is sweeping the dirt under the rug.

Comment: Evil coding style.  Variable, Function and class names should differ by more than case.  Some people use a coding style where members are prefixed with `m_`.  This helps when reading to differentiate member variables from parameters or functions.  In your posted code, the `Kg` vs. `kg` could be mistaken for a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if the parameters that I'm allowed to pass to Food's constructor can only be the parameters declared inside Pizza's constructor?

You are trying to pass variables that don't exist yet when calling `Food`'s constructor. They are local to the *body* of `Pizza`'s constructor, but `Food` must be initialized first before the body of `Pizza`'s constructor is entered.

> how can I pass parameters into Food that aren't Pizza parameters?

You have a few choices:

- add them to Pizza's constructor, and make them optional if desired:

  `Pizza(int flavor, int kg = 0, int quality = 0) : Food(kg, quality)`
- use helper functions that return the desired `Food` values, such as calculated from `Pizza`'s parameter:

  `Pizza(int flavor) : Food(getKgFor(flavor), getQualityFor(flavor))`
- just hard-code the values:

  `Pizza(int flavor) : Food(0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you cannot directly use local variables from the derived class constructor as arguments for the base class constructor in the member initializer list. The base class constructor is called before entering the body of the derived class constructor, so the local variables like `tempKg` and `tempQuality` are not yet in scope at that point.

If you want to pass parameters to the base class constructor that are not directly related to the derived class constructor parameters, you should pass them as arguments to the derived class constructor and then use them in the member initializer list for the base class.

You could do it like this. I have mentioned the edited code of your's below.

```
class Food
{
public:
    int Kg, Quality;
    Food(int kg, int quality) : Kg(kg), Quality(quality) {}
    ~Food() {}
};

class Pizza : public Food
{
public:
    int Flavor;

    Pizza(int flavor, int kg, int quality) : Food(kg, quality), Flavor(flavor)
    {
        // Additional initialization for Pizza if needed
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Example usage
    Pizza myPizza(1, 500, 80);
    
    // Accessing members from the base class
    int pizzaWeight = myPizza.Kg;
    int pizzaQuality = myPizza.Quality;
    int pizzaFlavor = myPizza.Flavor;

    // Rest of your program...
    return 0;
}
```

This way, you can pass additional parameters to the `Pizza` constructor and use them to initialize both the derived class members and the base class members.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers state, two possible solutions are to either hardcode the arguments to `Food` or add them as arguments to `Pizza`.

If you want to avoid hardcoding the parameters as `Food(0, 0)`, you may consider creating `const`/`constexpr` and/or `static` variables in the `Pizza` class for the values of `kg` and `quality`. Then, you can use those variables as arguments to the `Food` constructor.

(`static` variables would be shared by all instances of the `Pizza` class, but this doesn't matter since they aren't modified.)

For example:

```
class Pizza : public Food
{
public:
    Pizza(int flavor) : Food(tempKg, tempQuality)
    {
        int Flavor = flavor;
    }

private: // or it can be public if you want
    static constexpr const int tempKg = 0;
    static constexpr const int tempQuality = 0;
};
```

Passing local variables from the constructor doesn't work because the call to the superclass (`Food`) constructor happens before the body of the `Pizza` constructor begins execution.

Comment: `defaultKg` instead of `tempKg` ;-)